# Write in polynomial in factored form in complex number

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

Write the following polynomial in factored form(in complex number):

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6$$

Also, is there general solution of factoring for $1+z+z^2...z^n$ types of polynomial?

Comment: Note: all I needed to do to get your post to render as is was to enclose the expressions in `$`-signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd extend Adi Dani's answer a bit
$$
1 + z^2 + \ldots + z^6 = \frac {1-z^7}{1-z}
$$
Now decompose $1-z^7$ in factors. In order to do that, find all roots of
$$
1-z^7 = 0 \\
z = \sqrt [7]1 = \sqrt[7]{e^{0\cdot pi}} = \{ e^{\frac {2\pi ki}7}\}, k = 0,1,\ldots,6
$$
So
$$
1-z^7 = \prod_{k = 0}^6 \left (z - e^{\frac {2\pi ki}7}\right)
$$
To remove singularity at $z = 1$ we can cancel first $z - e^{\frac 07} = z-1$ term with denominator. So
$$
\sum_{k=0}^6 z^k = \prod_{k=1}^6 \left(z-e^{\frac {2\pi ki}7} \right) 
$$

### Update

I overlooked second part of the problem, but it's pretty much the same as Adi Dani's answer
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n z^k = \frac {1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} = \frac {\displaystyle \prod_{k = 0}^n \left(z-e^{\frac {2\pi ki} n} \right)}{1-z} = \prod_{k = 1}^n \left(z-e^{\frac {2\pi ki}n} \right)
$$

Comment: Thanks Kaster! I think that is the answer except it should be e^i2pik/7    but yes I will accept the answer!

Comment: @EricKim damn, you're right. I completely forgot about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=\frac{1-z^7}{1-z}$$

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+...+z^n=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

Denote $$1+z+z^2+...+z^n=S$$ then multiply by z we get
$$z+z^2+...+z^{n+1}=Sz$$ 
from firs equation subtract the second then solve by $S$

Comment: Thanks Adi
Could you please explain how you got that answer?(sorry I am newb at this)

Comment: Answer is edited

Comment: Sorry I thought that was the answer but it needs to be in factored form.

Comment: @AdiDani you answer has a singularity at $z=1$ but initial form doesn't.

Comment: Why downvote? It's quite correct, just unfinished.

Comment: I will upvote it once I have enough points :S

Comment: Deriving the geometric series formula in detail seems... tangential to the topic. (I did not downvote)